# How to add extra parameters inside a group by function?

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to modify the existing implementation.I need to add three new properties inside in children.
I have those properties inside the temp list .I need to fetch from the temp list but could not able to proceed.

`````
  List<EmployeeModel> temp = Response.ResponseData.OrderBy(x =>
   x.EmployeeNumber).ToList();
               var results = temp.GroupBy(p => p.Empoyeegroup.Name, p => (p.Empoyeegroup.Name + "_" + p.Empoyeenumber.ToString()),
               (key, g) => new FoodNode
               {
                   Name = key,
                   Children = new List<FoodNode>(from pp in g
                                                 select new FoodNode { Name = pp}).ToList()
                                              });
````
`````

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:
Select all required properties in group by and use them later. please check example.

```
var results = temp.GroupBy(p => p.Empoyeegroup.Name, p => new  {Name=p.Empoyeegroup.Name + "_" + p.Empoyeenumber.ToString(),Extra=p.Empoyeenumber},
                (key, g) => new FoodNode
                {
                    Name = key,
                    Children = new List<FoodNode>(from pp in g
                        select new FoodNode { Name = pp.Name,ExtraProp = pp.Extra}).ToList()
                });
```

Solution 2:
Select full object in group by instead of limited properties and use them whatever property required. Please check example.

```
var results = temp.GroupBy(p => p.Empoyeegroup.Name, p => p,
                (key, g) => new FoodNode
                {
                    Name = key,
                    Children = new List<FoodNode>(from pp in g
                        select new FoodNode { Name = (pp.Empoyeegroup.Name + "_" + pp.Empoyeenumber.ToString()),ExtraProp = pp.Empoyeenumber }).ToList()
                });
```